# how to clone two repository in Gitlab to local

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two repository in GitLab, and I should push project in both.

Should I clone two repository in same project, and then push?
How to clone two repository in one project?

Comment: [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem)?

Comment: If I do not clone, I will have a problem when I want to merg

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your project is a Git repository on its own, which gets push in its own GitLab repository.

Your other repositories can add your project repo as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
Clone those two repositories, and in each one:

```
git submodule add -b main https://gitlab.com/<me>/<myProject>
```

That will create a myProject subfolder, which actually references your project repositories.
At any point, in your two clones, you can do a `git submodule update --remote` in order to refresh the project subfolder, pulling its latest commit from its own `main` branch.